# numFound changes on changing start and rows

Tags: solr

[start = 0](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SgUgj.png)

[start = 581](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eIN15.png)

I got different numFound on same query with only changing the "start" and "rows", but in my understanding, numFound will always be the same.

I search google but only get one link about this situation, I will post below.

This guy had the same problem with me and yet still not have been solved, and its five years ago...

Could anybody help me?

Comment: http://lucene.472066.n3.nabble.com/numFound-changes-on-changing-start-and-rows-td3999752.html

Comment: If you are using older version of Solr, Upgrade it to newer version.

Comment: do you also have 2 shards?

Comment: @I am using solr 6.0, relatively new right?

Comment: @Mysterion one, and its replica

Comment: @Janny, yes, the version should be fine, i think

Answer (score 0):

Did you set a timeAllowed for your query? Consider setting this to false if you do.

See: https://wiki.apache.org/solr/CommonQueryParameters#timeAllowed

Comment: Thank you for you response, but I have checked everywhere in my  solrconfig.xml, though I did not found out where to set it to false, while I never gave a value to it......